# Why is my client server unable to send emails over port 587 while a telnet connection to my mail server is possible?

Tags: ssl, email, sasl, relay

Host cannot send mail over relay host with port 587.

I have two servers. One mail server and one server that uses the mail server as a relay host.

The client server should send over Port 587.
A telnet connection is possible between the client and mail server on port 587.
But trying to send mail results in the following lines (/var/log/maillog):

```
May 23 07:16:56 mail postfix/smtpd[15476]: connect from HOST_DNS[HOST_IP]
May 23 07:16:56 mail postfix/smtpd[15476]: disconnect from HOST_DNS[HOST_IP] ehlo=1 auth=0/2 quit=1 commands=2/4
```

EDIT:

I also get this in maillog:

```
May 23 09:32:13 187 postfix/smtp[402991]: maps_find: smtp_sasl_password_maps: MYHOSTNAME: not found
May 23 09:32:13 187 postfix/smtp[402991]: maps_find: smtp_sasl_password_maps: [MYHOSTNAME]:587: not found
```

In main.cf:

```
relayhost=[MYHOSTNAME]:587
```

and in /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd:

```
[MYHOSTNAME]:587 user@domain:password
```

SOLVED THIS PART: Syntax error in sasl_passwd and missing postmap command. Problem above still exists.

Comment: Does the client authenticate? SMTP/MSA requires authentication.

Comment: It was a syntax error in the sasl_passwd file, now the authentication works so i can send a mail with the terminal function mail. But if i will send it over php I still get the errors above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have in addition to

```
relayhost = [MYHOSTNAME]:587
```

also enabled authentication to MYHOSTNAME with:

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

The `maps_find:` error suggests that you did not update the Postfix lookup after updating  the plain text file `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`  with [`sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`](https://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I already set auth enable.

Comment: With maps_find you were right, but I still cannot send mails with the php function. I see no errors in the log the connection just does not work...

Comment: Is your PHP code configured to use the system mail functionality i.e. /usr/lib/sendmail or is it more sophisticated code that attempts to make  SMTP connection ?

Comment: I use the system mail. In my config are entries like:
mailpath: /usr/sbin/sendmail
smtp_host: myhostname
and smtp_port: 587

and my suspicion is that sendmail has problems with port 587, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: I found an error message regarding my sendmail problem.
**Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first**

Comment: It looks like you're not allowed to authenticate over a clear text channel ; which makes sense. Add a setting 
`smtp_use_tls = yes` and you may also need to add `smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` (with the correct path to where on your system the CA certificate bundle  is stored ) answered edited as well to reflect that

Comment: I think thats the actual problem. I activated these settings but it is still not working. Same error. Is it possible that I have to install a diffrent certificate first?

Comment: Thanks, the smtp_tls_CAfile helped to solve the problem.